# Unexpected fgets behavior on EOF

Tags: c, eof, fgets

I have this code that gets a line from stdin:

```
char string[USR_SIZE+1];
/*USR_SIZE is 9 */ 
fgets(string, USR_SIZE, stdin);
size_t len = strlen(string);
if (string[len-1] == '\n') {
    // read in whole line, no need to clear buffer
    string[len-1] = 0;
}    
else {
    if(feof(stdin)){
        printf("EXACT LEN\n");
    }
    else{
        //username too long, clear stdin and retry
        printf("Dumping...");
        dump_line(stdin); //clear stdin
        /*something that loops until success*/

    }

}
```

No newline in the buffer `string` means either `EOF` or that the string was cut.

Now. The optimal string needed is like `"user_123"` (8 char). Now if I type `"user_12345678"` it correctly stores only `"user_123"` and executes the else body. If I type `"user_123"` it executes else body too.

I want to distinguish a `"user_123"` (`EOF`) string from a `"user_1234"` (cutted) because of only in this last case input is not correct. Why `feof` is not set ?

Furthermore: how i can check `fgets` return value for error managament?

Found this solution:

```
if (fgets(string, USR_SIZE + 1, stdin)){
    if (strlen(string) == USR_SIZE && string[USR_SIZE - 1] == '\n'){
        printf("EXACT\n");
        /* User entered an eight character string. */
        string[USR_SIZE - 1] = 0;
    }
    else{
        if(strlen(string) < USR_SIZE-1){
        printf("INVALID<<<\n");
        /*don't dump*/
    }
        else{
            printf("INVALID>>>\n");
            dump_line(stdin);
        }
    }

    printf("EXIT\n");
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
else{
    free(auth_data);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR_("Error while getting user input\n");
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you're clear: simply entering a line and pressing enter will not generate EOF, no matter if it's too short or too long.

Comment: I don't get your point. I need to clear the stream if user types a string with more than 8 char. Right?

Comment: If the user types more than 8 chars, the remainder will be left in stdin, yes. But I think you're confusing EOF with enter.

Comment: @teppic Maybe we had a misunderstanding. I know that enter doesn't equals to EOF on stdin. Did I make some kind of mistake in the last code that let you think that?

Comment: Your last code would be fine if the user enters 8 characters followed by a newline. If they enter 8 characters and then EOF, it wouldn't work.

Comment: I tried it. Works with `"user_123"` as well! `fgets` adds itself a newline character at the end of the string if EOF is not reached or string is not cutted.

Comment: `fgets` doesn't add a newline. It copies one if you entered it, but never adds one.

Comment: Ok. Could you write a input string that fails my solution. I can't found one. It works for every input.

Comment: As I said, 8 characters + EOF will fail. Remember that if you type 8 characters and press enter, `fgets` reads **9** chars. If you enter 8 characters and EOF, `fgets` reads **8**.

Comment: Now i get the point, but I can't explain why now works really well. If i type :
`user_123`: prints `EXACT`; `EXIT`; `user_123`;. with `user_1234`: prints `INVALID>>>` `EXIT`; `user_123`;. Finally with `user_12` : prints `INVALID<<<`; `EXIT`; `user_12`;

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, if you want to allow for 8 characters and EOF as well as a newline:

```
char buf[10];
fgets(buf, 10, stdin);

int len=strlen(buf);
if (buf[len-1] == '\n') buf[len-1] = '\0';
if (strlen(buf) == 8)
    puts("Correct length");
else
    puts("Incorrect length");
```

(`fgets` isn't tested for success in this example)